# swift tableviewcell reference in drag and drop

Tags: swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make the textView in the cells of my TableView a drag source.

Easy enough:

```
textView.addInteraction(UIDragInteraction)
```

BUT

I can find no way of referencing this textView. It is defined in my custom tablecell file, TableViewCell.swift, and I just cannot find a way to reference it in my ViewController.swift file. Not allowed to make an @IBOutlet for it. After days of trying, I give up.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

}
```

Anyone know how to reference a member of my TableViewCell.swift class in my ViewController.swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cellForRow, do the following and no need to add an outlet in your ViewController. Outlet is already set in your tableView cell. So you can access like cell.textView...

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
cell.textView.text = your data
```

Comment: That looks great, Sugyana. I still can't get it to work, but I'm trying to hunt down the error I must have made somewhere. I do think this is the solution...

Comment: Just type cell.textView.text = your data and run. You will get it

Comment: How do I accept? I upvoted, but because I have only 1 point, it isn't shown.